# How to reverse characters in a line using Python

Tags: python

I want to reverse characters in a line of a text file, sample text file content is as below,

```
ABCDEF
EFGHIJ
013236
```

Expected output is,

```
FEDCBA
JIHGFE
632310
```

I have tried using `readlines()`, but I ended up reversing the order of lines as well.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through a file and get the reverse of each line with slicing:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip('\n')[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate line by line and then reverse characters in each line. After that join them at last to produce desired output.

```
>>> with open('new.txt', 'r') as f:
...     print(''.join([line[::-1] for line in f.readlines()]))
... 

FEDCBA
JIHGFE
632310
```